# "briefed them on " or "on the meeting"?

Tags: phrases

> The White House said in a statement that the Chinese government
>   briefed them **on** the meeting Tuesday.

Which part is connected "on"?

Comment: What exactly is the source of your confusion? If I'm going to brief you on something, I'm going to provide you with a piece of important information pertaining to it. The preposition *on* is part of the phrase *to brief someone on something*. Do you understand?

Comment: I understand now :) (after you commentted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "on" is equivalent to "about".  It doesn't mean "above" or "on top of".  It's an idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: "The Chinese government briefed them." "On what did they brief them?" "On the meeting. They briefed them on the meeting."

Comment: Hehe. Previously, I confused, if the Chinese had a meeting with American and the Chinese told them about the King visiting China.
Now, I know it.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I should say "finally I got it" instead of "I know it." Thanks!